# Push docker image to registry installed using microk8s addon

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tcp, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I am running multinode k8s cluster on my workstation. I have created the VM's using multipass. K8s cluster is deployed using microk8s.

Microk8s provides private registry as a [addon](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/blob/8bf6e65e9ed5f0749f43882c31787765ad91af1b/microk8s-resources/actions/registry.yaml).

It is providing 32000 as node port for the registry.

I would like to connect to this cluster remotely and push docker images to this registry.

I have added `172.**.44.***:32000` as insecure registery in my docker settings in my remote pc.

Note: `172.**.44.***` is the IP of the cluster (something you get in kubectl cluster-info)

But I am unable to make it work

```
docker build -t 172.**.44.***:32000/myapp:v1 .
docker push 172.**.44.***:32000/myapp:v1
Get http://172.**.44.***:32000/v2/: dial tcp 172.**.44.***:32000: connect: no route to host
```

---

I didn't use `microk8s` to set up kubernetes cluster before, but I do have the feeling is, the ip of `172.xx.xx.xx` is the wrong IP that you can't connect it from your local pc.

so what's the output of below commands:

1. What's the nodes IP, include master and work nodes?

```
kubernetes get nodes -o wide
```

2. What's the service setup?

```
kuberentes get services
```

can you make sure the service to that's private registry server's port is setup and can be connected.

3. check your own PC's IP

```
# for windows
ipconfig

# for linux/macos
ifconfig
```

maybe there are many IPs in output, make sure you get the proper local IP for your PC.

For example, it is something like `10.xx.xx.xx`, then you should use similar IPs to connect to that private registry server, you just need find it out

4. check what network CNI you are using, weavenet, flannel, etc.

the IP of `172.xx.xx.xx` are mostly used by these network CNI provider, it can be used in kubernetes cluster, but not your local host.

Comment: Is the docker "remote pc" not the machine running the VMs? You will probably need to use a bridged network adapter on the VM to make it accessible via the network, or map ports via your hypervisor. `multipass` itself doesn't really provide that level of control over network setup.

Comment: please add the output of this two commands in order to troubleshoot your IP problem: `kubectl get services` and `kubectl get nodes -o wide` .

Answer (score 3):

After you enable registry on the microk8s, run this script

```sh
kubectl get svc -n container-registry
```

you can see that microk8s has redirect registry service's port `32000` to `5000`, then I use `ingress` to expose via https.

First, you have to enable `ingress` on microk8s:

```
microk8s.enable ingress
```

then, you have to create a `tls sceret` if you want to use https :

```sh
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out server.key 2048

openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -x509 -days 3650 -out server.crt

kubectl create secret tls registry-secret-tls --cert=server.crt --key=server.key -n container-registry
```

then use `kubectl apply -f` to create an `ingress` for revese proxy of `registry` service.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: registry
  namespace: container-registry
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "500m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-pass-headers: "Location"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ingress.local
    secretName: registry-secret-tls
  rules:
  - host: ingress.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: registry
          servicePort: 5000
```

then, add `127.0.0.1 ingress.local` to `/etc/hosts` file. 
At last, use `buildah` push docker images to `ingress.local`.

```sh
buildah push --tls-verify=false 44c92e82c220 docker://ingress.local/datacenter-school
```

This time, it looks everything is ok. But when I try list images in microk8s, I can't find the image that I just pushed.

```sh
microk8s.ctr images ls -q |grep datacenter-school
```

That's quiet weird!